# Find all possible unique path in mXn matrix

Tags: recursion, matrix, path

Help me in finding all possible path to reach bottom right most cell from top left most cell in mXn matrix.

Below are the restrictions,

1. Can not visit the cell which is already visited.
2. Should visit all cell before reaching exit i.e. bottom right most cell.

Tried few logic's but not able to get all paths. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest idea is to recursively try every possible non-self-crossing path, and every time such a path hits the bottom-right corner check whether it's length equals the number of all cells.

Here comes a very naive [and thus slow and memory-consuming] implementation in js (judging by your profile you know js), just to point the algorithm in a formal, unequivocal way. You're interested in the "OK, let's do this!" part, before are only some helpers to make this example actually executable:

```
function paths(M,N) {
    // is given pos present in list of poss?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    var pos_member = function(pos,poss) {
        for(var i=0;i<poss.length;i++)
            if(pos[0]==poss[i][0] && pos[1]==poss[i][1])
                return true;
        return false;
    };
    // all positions present in poss1 and not in poss2:                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    var positions_diff = function(poss1,poss2) {
        var poss_d = [];
        for(var i=0;i<poss1.length;i++)
            if(pos_member(poss1[i],poss2)==false)
                poss_d.unshift(poss1[i]);
        return poss_d;
    };
    // where can you go from [x,y] ?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    var all_next_positions = function([x,y]) {
        var poss = [];
        // assuming no diagonal moves are allowed;                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        // otherwise add 4 more next possible positions.                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        if(x > 0) poss.unshift([x-1,y]);
        if(x < M-1) poss.unshift([x+1,y]);
        if(y > 0) poss.unshift([x,y-1]);
        if(y < N-1) poss.unshift([x,y+1]);
        return poss;
    };

    //////// OK, let's do this! //////////////////////////////////                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    var pending = [ [[0,0]] ]; // pending partial paths (looks like an owl statring at you, doesn't it?)                                                                                                                                                                        
    var results = []; // corect paths found so far                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    while(pending.length>0) {
        var current = pending.shift();
        var last_pos = current[0];
        if(last_pos[0]==M-1 && last_pos[1]==N-1) {
            /// it reaached the goal, but did it visit all the cells?                                                                                                                                                                                                           
            if(current.length == M*N) /// yes it did, so keep it.                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                results.unshift(current);
        } else {
            /// keep going...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            var next_poss = positions_diff(all_next_positions(last_pos), current);
            for(var i=0;i<next_poss.length;i++) {
                var candidate = current.slice(0); /// clone, because call by reference is evil.                                                                                                                                                                                 
                candidate.unshift(next_poss[i]);
                pending.unshift(candidate);
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

For sure you want to represent positions differently, and for larger "matrices" you'd have to get rid of "wrong paths" asap., but hope this gets you started somewhere.